# Broken Wordpress Content on IIS

Tags: windows, wordpress, iis

I migrated wordpress from linux to IIS. Site loads completely within web server.

After changing the site url and home to IP address of the server (it was localhost), the site appears but with broken images / theme.

Any suggestions?

Cheers,

p

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. We need to know the details of how it is broken, what you expected, and the source code you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you may have to look out for within wordpress when doing the transfer.

First is checking the IP/localhost hasn't been set anywhere and that it is the domain url being used on the GUID's or links within posts. Using a plugin such as find and replace (http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) will help find all the errors.

The next problem i have encountered the most is the database connections. Be sure to edit the wp-config.php with the new database details and also amend any other document which they may be included in. I have transfered some websites before and the new provider might have added their own prefix or the MySQL server may not be localhost.

If the website isn't a simple move and requires a new install of WordPress, remember to transfer the theme and all of the plugins including the settings first. THEN install the backup of data. If you import the backed up data before having everything ready, it can cause pages to break or have missing elements.

You can find alot more information on the WordPress official docs: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: Thanks!! It was a mixture of errant localhost entries, which I found to be in: the link within the site (pages, images, .. ) and wp-config.php (siteurl and home).